# Default front view for SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I have just implemented an `SWRevealViewController` into my application and I have one problem.

The `front view` (the view on top of the table view) is not the view controller I want on top. I have `two view controllers` which I link to from my table view and the one I don't want displaying shows up.

How can I set One of the two view controllers I want at the front upon app launch?

Comment: Please share any design of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
   let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
   let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController

   let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
   var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

   let sidebar = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  “sideVCID”)as! Sidebar
   let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVCID")as!HomeVC

   frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: home);
   rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sidebar)

   revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController;
   revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController;
   revealController.delegate = self;
   mainRevealController  = revealController
   self.window?.rootViewController =  = mainRevealController
```

Comment: This answer confuses me. I have all of my storyboard laid out with the segues but what I need is one of the controllers to always appear first. I don't know where to put this code and it certainly doesn't look like it is in the viewWillAppear method which I would have thought would be ideal

Comment: You can use  Login  button click or if you want to make home page than use this code in didfinishlaunch

Comment: How do I attach it to the view on the storyboard

Comment: No need to attach in storyboard only give storyboard id  ex -> HomeVCID of your view controller and write the above code